# Last Index в БД

Tags: база-данных, mysql

Как определить последнюю добавленную ID в таблицу?

Comment: на mysql или на php?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT-1 FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE table_name='table1'
```

альтернативно но не гламурно:

```
SELECT MAX(ID) from table1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [mysql_insert_id()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php)